# TypeScript: How do you specify an inlined object's type?

Tags: typescript

I've got some code that compiles when I do this:

```
    const createCallback: any = {
        toBuffer: (func: any) => {
            return func();
        }
    };
    pdfCreateMock.returns(createCallback);
```

How do I get it to compile like this?

```
    pdfCreateMock.returns({
        toBuffer: (func: any) => {
            return func();
        }
    });
```

I don't know how to say that the inlined object is of type `any`.  This is the error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast to any

```
pdfCreateMock.returns(<any>{
        toBuffer: (func: any) => {
            return func();
        }
    });
```